# Sitecore RTE add new font style

Tags: sitecore-client

I'm going to do some customization with the Rich Text Editor in my sitecore instance I'd like to add another font style in it. Base on what I've read so far I should edit the toolsfile.xml. Reference below.

http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/editor/functionality/toolbars/using-toolsfile.xml

I've already added the font name in the file but I want to know how will it read the font that I added? Do I need to put the font file somewhere in my instance?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need to add new fonts you can add them in the RTE Profile in the `core` database:

[image: Full RTE Profile]

Note that this is the `Rich Text Full` profile, by default Sitecore is configured to use the `Rich Text Default` profile:

```
<setting name="HtmlEditor.DefaultProfile" value="/sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/Rich Text Default" />
```

However, I would recommend that you do not use font styles in RTE, it will make your life more tough in the long term and is not best practice. If the business decides to change the default font then you will have to mnaully go through content and change them.

Instead use CSS styles and set the font to use in that stlye declaration. You can link a CSS Stylesheet to the RTE and add your custom styles in there so users can select them. Either update the default css files or link to a custom stylesheet and update the setting in config:

```
<setting name="WebStylesheet" value="/default.css" />
```

The users will be able to select the styles in RTE then:

[image: RTE CSS Styles]