# Custom fonts issue in Sitecore Content Editor (Rich Text Editor and Single Line Text Fields)

Tags: content-editor

We are running through one issue in Sitecore, Please let me know if anyone faced similar issue and know the solution. We are trying to copy content from MSWord (Which uses custom fonts "Times new roman navajo" downloadURL: https://www.dinecollege.edu/current_students/current-students/ ) to Sitecore content editor, When we copy the content it is coming in unreadable format as showing in the below screenshot. Can you please suggest how to fix this.

[image]

It should come like below:
[image]

Comment: RTE is a standard word processing tool but in Sitecore, stylesheets and website templates determine the UI and format. You will lose the fonts and font size when you will paste the content from MS word - https://doc.sitecore.com/users/93/sitecore-experience-platform/en/paste-content-from-microsoft-word-into-a-rich-text-field.html

Comment: Hi Mark, Thanks for reply. I tried this "Paste Word" option but still it is not working. In ms word we used custom fonts.

Answer (score 0):

There could be 2 problems here:

1. Different character encoding in Word document and in Sitecore. You [can try](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/choose-text-encoding-when-you-open-and-save-files-60d59c21-88b5-4006-831c-d536d42fd861) to save MS
   Word file using UTF-8 encoding. Then copy text with new encoding and try if it works.
2. You use characters that are not available in the default font. In this case, you need to use the same font for RTE and on the website itself. You need to [find setting](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/3036/sitecore-rte-add-new-font-style) `WebStylesheet` in your config files. It will point you to `css` file with styles for RTE. You need to add your font in this stylesheet file. Also you will need to add your font to common stylesheet file on your website (But that is different in each Sitecore installation, I could not point you).

Comment: Hi Anton, Thanks for your reply. Yes 2nd option might be the right. MS Word content is created using some custom fonts (Times new roman navajo) which are not available on sitecore. As per your answer if i include in CSS file will it work for single line text also?

Comment: @NarenderReddyK
The single-line text field has no ability to use custom fonts.